# Unable to locate element within frame(s) in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, frames

Relatively new to Python and I'm looking to create an automation that goes to this site, and clicks a button. For some reason its very tough for me to find the element I'm looking for.

Here is an example of the script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
chrome_driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
#import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
driver.maximize_window()

#driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("http://listyourself.net")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)
#driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name_or_id")
#element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
#   EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myNavbar"]/ul/li[2]/a'))
#)

element_inside_frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"#//a[contains(text(), 'individual')]"))
)

element_inside_frame.click()
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
#//a[contains(text(), 'individual')]
#element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myNavbar"]/ul/li[2]/a')
#element.click()


#logging.info('element clicked successfully')

#driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

The script gets to the site fine but it waits the entire 10 seconds and gives me a "elenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace" error & im assuming its because its unable to find the element for the "individual" button im looking to click on.

As you can see from the script i've tried almost everything, xpath, (theres no id or name for the element, text, tried creating my own xpath, all of which were confirmed to exist and be 1on1 in the console.

How do i troubleshoot this? I'm at a stand still and all of the other stackoverflow posts did not help.

Here is the website code for refrence.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyAXD.png)

The highlighted element is what im trying to click on, the "individual" button. I am using chrome on a mac and updated versions of selenium, webdriver, and pip. Please advise. Thank you

I've tried all of the troubleshooting methods to no success.

Comment: update: i've added some print statements at the end of every action in the script and it supposedly does everything I'd like it to do but the button im looking to click that manually would navigate to another page isnt going anywhere. Please let me know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your page has several frames, looks like when you getting first frame, needed frame has not been completely rendered yet, so you got wrong frame.

Don't use indexes if you can, it's bad practice. Instead of it wait for frame presence by locator `frame[src]` and then go inside it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("http://listyourself.net")
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'frame[src]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

element_inside_frame = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[href*=listing]"))
)
element_inside_frame.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually worked! When navigating further actions in this site (most of the pages are structured the same way) should i always use the frame[src] to access certain elements? When I try to perform an action on the individual page using a similar code but different actions, I get similar results wherein it just waits and successfully completes the code but doesn't perform the action im looking for. What am i missing conceptually?

Comment: this is what im trying to add that doesnt seem to be working

Comment: `code
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'frame[src]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
element_inside_frame = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[placeholder="Fist Name"]'))
)
element_inside_frame.send_keys("Jonathan")
driver.switch_to.default_content() `

Comment: @JonathanPierre, yes, every time you want to click something on navbar, you should switch context to frame and then go back to default_content if you finished interaction with nav bar.

So I suggest you to wrap navigation in separate method.